# Create matrix by layering array

Tags: r, matrix

I have an array of number

```
x <- seq(1:10)
```

I am after a matrix with `n` rows. Here is an example with 3-row matrix:

```
1   2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
NA  1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8   9
NA  NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8
```

What would be the best way to create one?

Comment: Is a solution using loops acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

There is an odd little function called `embed` that will do it...

```
t(embed(c(NA, NA, 1:10), 3))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
[2,]   NA    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
[3,]   NA   NA    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8
```

For a vector `x` and a matrix of `n` rows, the equivalent would be

```
t(embed(c(rep(NA, n-1), x), n))
```

Comment: I've added a line generalising the result to your example.

Comment: Probably even `t(embed(c(rep(NA, length(x)-1), x), length(x)))`. Anyway, a nice option :)

Comment: @tmfmnk No, that would be different - `n` is independent of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is more simpler way to do this but one way to create this matrix would be

```
create_matrix <- function(x, n) {
   t(sapply(seq(n), function(m) c(rep(NA, m - 1), head(x, length(x) - m + 1))))
}

create_matrix(1:10, 3)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#[2,]   NA    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8     9
#[3,]   NA   NA    1    2    3    4    5    6    7     8


create_matrix(c(4, 3, 6, 8, 7), 4)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    4    3    6    8    7
#[2,]   NA    4    3    6    8
#[3,]   NA   NA    4    3    6
#[4,]   NA   NA   NA    4    3
```